# iptable snat with ovs bridge

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Is there a way to make iptable masquerade rule to work with ovs.

I tried this

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

It works for linux bridge but not for ovs. Any suggestions to make it work for ovs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: no it didn't work.

Comment: I figure it out on my end. My filter table was dropping packets. Doing a iptables -F -t filter fixed it for me.

Comment: so is snat working with ovs bridge for you?

Comment: I should specifically try SNAT sometime soon. I did MASQUERADE rather than SNAT. MASQUERADE basically does SNAT, except it applies to all source addresses on the interface designated with MASQUERADE. It's kind of a catch all brute force approach I guess. When I have time, I will try SNAT, but I suspect it would work too.